# Visit generic heterogeneous collection in a type safe and ergonomic way

Tags: kotlin, generics

The goal is to store a list of generic objects (of different type argument) in a list and operate on them in a type safe and ergonomic way.

My current design uses a visitor pattern:

```kotlin
sealed interface Element {
  fun visit(visitor: Visitor)
}

interface Visitor {
  fun <T> accept(elementA: ElementA<T>)
}

data class ElementA<T>(
    // example members, many more in the real code
    val produce : () -> T,
    val doSomething: (T) -> Unit
) : Element {
  override fun visit(visitor: Visitor) = visitor.accept(this)
}
```

Nevertheless the visitor is not very convenient to write as one has to subclass `Visitor`:

```kotlin
fun exampleUse(elements: List<Element>) {
  for (element in elements) {
    element.visit(object : Visitor {
      override fun <T> accept(elementA: ElementA<T>) {
        // We don't care about the actual type T, just that it exists
        elementA.doSomething(elementA.produce())
      }
    })
  }
}
```

It's not very ergonomic, and I would like for users to only have to write conventional and short code like
`element.visit {it.doSomething(it.produce())}`.

The only requirements are that:

- the elements should be storable in a list (homogeneous collection)
- the usage (eg: `a.doSomething(a.produce())`) should kept be separated from the class as they are defined in different package with different concerns.

If there is a way to avoid the visitor boilerplate, it's even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to satisfy your requirements (I am assuming `Element` exists only as a common supertype for all `ElementA<Something>`):

```
data class ElementA<T>(
    // example members, many more in the real code
    val produce : () -> T,
    val doSomething: (T) -> Unit
)

// optional
typealias Element = ElementA<*>

// or fun exampleUse(elements: List<ElementA<*>>)
// if you don't create Element
fun exampleUse(elements: List<Element>) {
  fun <T> use(elementA: ElementA<T>) {
    // We don't care about the actual type T, just that it exists
    elementA.doSomething(elementA.produce())
  }
    
  for (element in elements) {
    use(element)
  }
}
```

Note that the local function can also be an extension function:

```
fun exampleUse(elements: List<Element>) {
  fun <T> ElementA<T>.use() {
    // We don't care about the actual type T, just that it exists
    doSomething(produce())
  }
    
  for (element in elements) {
    element.use()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements, but I implemented a type-safe heterogenous map in Kotlin: https://github.com/broo2s/typedmap . It is a little different than your example, because it is not a list, but a map. You can use it for example like this:

```
val map = simpleTypedMap()
sess += User("alice")
val user = sess.get<User>()
```

You can still store multiple items per a key type, but as this is a map, each item has to be uniquely identifiable, so I'm not sure if this suits you:

```
map[UserKey(1)] = User("alice")
map[UserKey(2)] = User("bob")

val alice = map[UserKey(1)]
val bob = map[UserKey(2)]
```

Comment: In fact, it probably makes sense to add a typed list or rather a multimap to my library. It would perfectly fit your problem and would be both more convenient and efficient than the visitor pattern,