# Overload resolution of reified generic in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I would like to return different type depending on a reified type parameter. I tried to use overloads but the overload resolution doesn't seem correct.

My goal is to store a close set of types at runtime like so:

```kotlin
sealed interface Type<T> {
  object Int: Type<kotlin.Int>
  object Boolean: Type<kotlin.Boolean>
}

inline fun<reified T> get() : Type<T> = getImpl(null as T?)

fun getImpl(a: Int?) : Type<Int> = Type.Int
fun getImpl(a: Boolean?) : Type<Boolean> = Type.Boolean
fun <T>getImpl(a: T?) : Type<T> = error("Unsupported type")

fun main() {
    println(getImpl(null as Int?)) // return Type.Int as expected
    println(get<Int>()) // Same as above after get is inlined but throws!
}
```

Could it be that the overload is resolved before the method is inlined?

The goal is for some generic classes to take a `Type<T>` parameter and be guaranty that T is in the closed set. It also allows for testing the generic type `T` at runtime (workaround type erasure).

I would rather avoid having the clients specify `Type.Int` explicitly or have an implementation using unchecked cast such as:

```
inline fun<reified T> getUncheckedCast() : Type<T> =
  when (T::class) {
    Int::class -> Type.IntType as Type<T>
    Boolean::class -> Type.BooleanType as Type<T>
    else -> error("Unsupported type")
  }
```

Comment: This is a follow up of my previous question [Visit generic heterogeneous collection in a type safe and ergonomic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259178/visit-generic-heterogeneous-collection-in-a-type-safe-and-ergonomic-way/68259651)

Comment: I understand your point and it seems technically possible, but I think this is more complicated than it seems. If `getImpl()` would be resolved at the call-site then how exactly the compiler would look for a specific `getImpl()` to use? It would scan the whole class path and choose randomly? Sounds like a terrible idea. It would require to import `getImpl()` to the code of call-site? Sounds reasonable, but wait, on the call-site we only see `get()` - how could we know we use `getImpl()` internally? Such feature would add a lot of confusion.

Comment: @broot This is a very good point. C++ supports this feature but has very complicated rules (eg: SFINAE, point of instantiation).  I now understand why this feature is not supported. If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't say this is the main reason why it is not supported. Honestly, I don't really know. But my intuition tells me that resolving inlines in a similar way as the source code would be copied to the call site is quite complicated approach and there may be even more problems like above. Reifying a type seems much simpler. Still, I think it would be great to be able to do what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#reified-type-parameters), the only difference `reified` parameter makes is that its runtime class is available:

> ##### 4.5.2 Reified type parametersLoad tests
>
> Type parameters of inline function declarations (and only those) can be declared reified using the corresponding keyword. A reified type parameter is a [runtime-available](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/runtime-type-information.html#runtime-available-types) type inside the function scope, see the corresponding section for details.

It doesn't specify that the type is substituted when the function is inlined.
This mean that `reified` is sugaring for implicitly passing the `KClass` of reified types:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T>f() = T.class
// is desugared to
inline fun <T>f(__TKClass : KClass<T>) = __TKClass
```

Thus the overload resolution set is not affected by reifying types.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be common to answer question by quoting the spec outside of C++. Please let me know if there is a better Kotlin reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last code block is the best solution. Although your `get` function is reified, the type is still generic so the compiler is going to resolve the overload as the generic one that throws an error. You can’t get the compiler to select which overload to call at runtime. It is always selected at compile time.

Comment: I don't believe this to be correct. Reified types are known at compile time (evidently by the fact that you can write `T::class` or `T is Int`), so I don't see why the right overload is not choose.

Comment: Overloads are chosen at compile time regardless of whether the type is known.

Comment: Overloads are chosen at compile time and T is known at compile time, so why is the overload resolution not using this information? Is there a way to make it use it?
It's especially confusing because when the inline function is inlined manually (aka copy the source code), then the correct overload is called.

Comment: T is not known at compile time. By definition generics are not known at compile time. If it were known, it would have a specific type. Maybe they theoretically could have made the compiler choose the overload at runtime by inlining the equivalent of a when statement that compares the class type of T, but for whatever reason, they didn’t. Could be an oversight, or could be intentionally choosing the path of fewest surprises, that reification should not modify the usual algorithm for overload resolution.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but note we are talking about inline functions. I believe the reason why Kotlin requires to mark function as inline in order to use reified params is just because inlining make possible to know T at compile time. If you look into generated bytecode you will notice that inlined code contains direct references to a true T type, e.g. String. I don't see why the compiler couldn't use this knowledge to resolve overloads.

Comment: But as I said in above comments, my guess is that inline functions are in fact compiled only once, in their def site. They contain some placeholders for reified types, for callbacks invoked in-place and maybe for some other tricks, but generally they are already compiled when they are mixed with the code of a calling function. This is why I think it is not that easy to resolve overloads.

Comment: Yes, i should clarify, the type is known at the call site, but internally in the function it is just like a Class parameter passed to the function. Internally, the type isn’t known, but is runtime-inspectable. I’m presuming that by design it works this way so logic is no different than with non-reified functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I read the Kotlin spec which confirm your last comment @Tenfour04. I took the liberty to answer my own question based on your comments and the spec.